# What's wrong with my dynamic programming solution for uva 10739?

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm solving [this](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1680) problem on uva. I've found the recurrence relation and it works perfectly for the given test cases. However, without memoization, it exceeds time limit. I cached the values and returned the cache(basic memoization). With caching, I'm getting an answer of 1 more than the actual answer for the last two test cases. I can't understand what might be the bug because it works if you take out the caching. Thanks for your help.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

    string a;
    int n;
    int dp[1005][1005];

        int solve(int i, int j, int moves)
            {
                if(j<=i)
                    return dp[i][j] = moves;

                if(dp[i][j]!=-1)
                return dp[i][j];

                if(a[i]==a[j])
                    return dp[i][j] = solve(i+1, j-1, moves);
                else
                    return dp[i][j] = min(min(solve(i+1, j-1, moves+1), solve(i+1, j, moves+1)), solve(i, j-1, moves+1));
        }

    int main()
        {
            int T;
            cin >> T;
            while(T--)
            {
                cin >> a;
                n = a.length();
                memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));
                int ans = solve(0, n-1, 0);
                cout << ans << "\n";
            }
        }
```

Expected O/P for:
sadrulhabibchowdhury: 8

My Output: 9

Comment: Have you tried debugging this?  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.  You should be able to supply a problem description (not a link -- see the SO intro tour), a properly annotated minimal program, and some sort of debugging attempt.  Your posting, standing alone, is not sufficient to reproduce the problem -- for instance, stick the input file into an array and change your main program to grab the values from there.  Then insert some output statements to trace the control and data flow, at least for the failing cases.

Comment: Also, explain how to turn memoization off and on, so we can reproduce the difference in execution.

Comment: I am sorry for not giving the steps to reproduce the problem. Just do not assign return statements to dp[I][j]. Remove all other lines which return from do[I][j]. Memoization is now turned off, gives the right answer. But too slow to get accepted though